# Using connectedness to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I want to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, for all $n \geq 2$ using the following hint:

> Consider connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but things left in $\mathbb{R}^n$

The hint seems to be incomplete and I would like to decipher what it is trying to say (so that I can attempt this question properly myself in full confidence).

Comment: What happens upon removal of exactly one point from the spaces?

Comment: I understand that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ is connected whereas $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is not. Is this what the hint is trying to say?

Comment: I think that's what the hint meant to say (I can't make too much sense of it as written).

Comment: Thanks for the confidence boost! I'll attempt the question with a happier conscience now.

Comment: Further qestion, why exactly one point? We can remove more than one point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and still preserve connectedness can't we? (as long as it's done in a nice enough way that sections of the space aren't isolated from each other) I realise that this isn't needed for the question, but this general aside came to mind.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But removal of just one suffices for a proof.

Comment: @IrregularUser Yes, you are right!. If we remove finitely many points from  $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\geq 2$) we will still have a connected space, which means that to decide whether or not $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $2\leq n<m$ we will have to be more creative.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone! And thanks for the additional question to consider @Wore

Comment: @IrregularUser: If you found the answer to your question, please consider self-answering your question, so that it gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: I suspect that the starting point for the hint was something like *Consider the image in* $\Bbb R$ *of a connected proper subset of* $\Bbb R^n$, and the author of the hint then either tried to make it more obscure or had trouble with the English.

Comment: @Shahab Just done so. I'll start leaving less unanswered questions of my own around from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a summary of what has been understood from the comments.

A nice extrapolation of what the hint is trying to say is that if we remove exactly one point from $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \geq 2$), then it is still connected. Whereas if we remove exactly one point from $\mathbb{R}$, then it is no longer connected.

Furthermore, we can actually remove finitely many points from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and still have a connected space, which means that to decide whether or not $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, for $2 \leq n < m$, we will have to be more creative.

However, for this particular question, considering the removal of one point from the spaces is enough.